# How to get an App made using JavaScript to autoresize for other Apple Devices?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, ipad

I've created an app using Javascript / CSS and HTML, just a simple game, nothing special.. however, when I run the game in xcode (iphone5 simulator) it runs fine, no problems and on an actual iPhone5 device using the ad-hoc method via my Apple Dev Account, but when I try it on the iPad mini and iPad 3 the game only show's up in the top left hand corner inside a  what can only be described as an iphone5 size screen. Question is, how using either JS, CSS or HTML do I tell the app (in xcode6) to resize to a device bigger than iphone5.. basically how do I tell the app to resize depending on device, I want to launch the game (hopefully!) for iphone5, 6 and all iPads of course.

I'm using xcode6 and iOS8

Many thanks in advance for any help given.

Would be happy to screenshare over Skype if this is easier to do? (Let me know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was iPhone has smaller width compare to iPad. You have develop an app for iPhone , so when u simulate it on iPad i only takes width upto 586px or 320px not all iPad width. This width can be adjusted by using media queries.

Add the following media queries with your stylesheet.

Use CSS media queries as follows

```
html
{
//default styles as you have used(for iPhone 5 as you said)
}
body
{
//default styles as you have used
}
.contianer(wrapper)
{
//default styles as you have used
}

//media queries for iPad 

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  
{ 
/* STYLES GO HERE */
//use width upto 768px
}

//media queries for iPad mini

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)
{ 
/* STYLES GO HERE */
}
```

Use proper width upto 1024px to 768px as it can match with iPad and you can get your app viewable for iPad.

Go to this [Link](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/#iPhone) for iphone and ipad styles.

Comment: Hi, could you give an example of the code above to show for iphone 6 and ipad mini please? Many thanks..

Comment: Go through the Link provided in answer.